# How to set default date in daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

Is there any way to simply set default date as current **+ 5 day ahead** in daterangepicker? Like this:

```
$('.selector').daterangepicker({
singleDatePicker: true,
showDropdowns: true,
setDate: '+5d',
minDate: new Date()
}, function(start, end, label) {
    $('.selector').val(start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like so. You also don't need that callback function since the format string is configurable.

```
$('.selector').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    startDate: moment().add(5, 'day'),
    minDate: moment(),
    locale: { 
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes @Dan. I was using some old version of daterangepicker.  I did this in exact this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 5;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
$('.selector').val(formatDate(someDate));
```

this helped

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.selector').daterangepicker({
singleDatePicker: true,
showDropdowns: true,
minDate: new Date()
}, function(start, end, label) { $('.selector').val(start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

});

var Today= new Date();
Today.setDate(Today.getDate() + 5);//any date you want
$('.selector').daterangepicker('setDate', Today);
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. A fiddle example would be great.

Comment: Could you put your code in fiddle? along with the scripts needed to run it so i can help?

Comment: `var someDate = new Date();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 5;
        someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
        
        $('.selector').val(formatDate(someDate));` this helped