# Daterangepicker default dates not working [Invalid date]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I am using [Daterangepicker](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js).

I am fetching start and end date from backend, it comes in string format. e.g (2020-02-22).

But when I pass those dates as default, it is not working.

My code :

HTML

```
<input name="daterange_x" type="text" class="form-control">
```

JS

```
var start_date = moment('2020-04-29').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var end_date = moment('2020-05-05').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

$('input[name="daterange_x"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'right',
    minDate:new Date(),
    startDate: start_date,
    endDate: end_date,
}, function(start, end, label) {
    start_date = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    end_date = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    $('#id_start_date').val(start_date);
    $('#id_end_date').val(end_date);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rmtest/d28g130q/3/

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: ok i will try ..

Comment: Thanks. That would help others to better understand and debug the issue and provide better solutions.

Comment: @palaѕн ==> https://jsfiddle.net/rmtest/d28g130q/3/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776463/how-to-set-default-date-in-daterangepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this issue by just setting the `locale` option for the daterangepicker to `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, the same format that you are using in getting `start_date` & `end_date` like:

```js
var start_date = moment('2020-04-29').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var end_date = moment('2020-05-05').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

$('input[name="daterange_x"]').daterangepicker({
  opens: 'right',
  minDate: new Date(),
  startDate: start_date,
  endDate: end_date,
  locale: {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  }
}, function(start, end, label) {
  start_date = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  end_date = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  $('#id_start_date').val(start_date);
  $('#id_end_date').val(end_date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<input name="daterange_x" type="text" class="form-control">
```